# The name 'Color' does not exist in the current context using iTextSharp

Tags: itext

I am using itextsharp dll for creating pdf.

I want to change my font color.

I found solution in Google.

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 88f, 88f, 10f, 10f);
Font NormalFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK);
```

But I try to my source code. It's show's an error The name 'Color' does not exist in the current context. Color class not fond.

How to solve this error.

Thank you.

My code below.

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;


    private void sPDF(DataRow row)
    {
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 88f, 88f, 10f, 10f);
        Font NormalFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK);

        using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
            Phrase phrase = null;
            PdfPCell cell = null;
            PdfPTable table = null;
            Color color = null;

            document.Open();

            //Separater Line
            color = new Color(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#A9A9A9"));
            DrawLine(writer, 25f, document.Top - 79f, document.PageSize.Width - 25f, document.Top - 79f, color);
            DrawLine(writer, 25f, document.Top - 80f, document.PageSize.Width - 25f, document.Top - 80f, color);
            document.Add(table);

            document.Close();
            byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            memoryStream.Close();

        }
    }

    private static void DrawLine(PdfWriter writer, float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, Color color)
    {
        PdfContentByte contentByte = writer.DirectContent;
        contentByte.SetColorStroke(color);
        contentByte.MoveTo(x1, y1);
        contentByte.LineTo(x2, y2);
        contentByte.Stroke();
    }
```

Comment: I can't see where you are trying to use the font you are trying to use. If you change it to `Font normalFont = new Font("Arial", 12, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK);`I think it might stop the error, but try removing the line completely. Or give an example of where you are trying to use it so we can help more

Comment: @Red I don't understand your comment. Please read my answer to see what's really going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I explained many times before, we don't talk about iTextSharp anymore. That name was changed to iText for .NET a couple of years ago. Looking at your code, I see that you are using an old version of iText (probably version 5). Today, we're at version 7. See the [tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net-version) and the [download page](https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/NET).

There are two answers to your question:

1. Please upgrade to iText 7, and use the iText 7 Color classes: http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText7/latest/com/itextpdf/kernel/colors/package-summary.html
2. If you insist on using an old version of iText (note: these versions are no longer supported), replace `Color` with `BaseColor`: http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText5/5.5.13/com/itextpdf/text/BaseColor.html

I don't know where you found documentation about using `Color`, but that information must be really old, because we changed `Color` into `BaseColor` in the year 2009.

To avoid further problems, please use the latest versions, and always consult the [official web site](https://itextpdf.com/).